# SwiftUI - weird spacing in HStack with two Texts

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I am creating a "News" SwiftUI widget and I need to display rows, each containing time and news header.

I am using a `VStack` containing `HStack`'s for each item but I am encountering an issue with extra HStack spacing between the two `Text`'s. I need the left `Text` taking all the width needed for its content and the right `Text` taking all the width that is left. Seems to work as expected for the longer date (second line) for not for the first one.

In AutoLayout world I would need to play around with Content hugging / Compression resistance priority to achieve what I need but not sure what to do in SwiftUI.

Here's my code for creating the view:

```
  private func createView(from headers: [NewsHeaderEntry.NewsHeader], with first: Int) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { metrics in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                title
                ForEach(headers[0...first - 1]) { header in
                    HStack(spacing: 4) {
                            Text(header.newsAt)
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .fontWeight(.light)
                                .background(.green)
                                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                            Text(header.title)
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .redacted(reason: header.isPlaceholder ? .placeholder : .init())
                                .background(.yellow)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
                        }
                        .background(.red)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: metrics.size.width)
            .background(.blue)
        }
    }
```

I have also tried setting `maxWidth: .infinity` for the left `Text` as well but it resulted in equal widths for both `Text`s which is not what I need.

[image: Result:]

**Update**: Without `.padding(.horizontal, 8)` the spacing works as expected but I need the horizontal spacing from the design perspective.

[[image: Result without padding:][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEEeD.jpg):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the default behavior of the stack. Your frame modifiers are the issue:

```swift
private func createView(from headers: [NewsHeaderEntry.NewsHeader], with first: Int) -> some View {
    GeometryReader { metrics in
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
            title
            ForEach(headers[0...first - 1]) { header in
                HStack(spacing: 4) {
                    Text(header.newsAt)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                        .background(.green)
                    Text(header.title)
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .redacted(reason: header.isPlaceholder ? .placeholder : .init())
                        .background(.yellow)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                }
                .background(.red)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: metrics.size.width)
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

[image: Simulator]